# Look ahead in groupby_dynamic

Tags: python-polars

When performing a groupby_dynamic on a index columns and aggregating a columns in a list (as to see which values are in the group), for a given group and a given index i, the values in the list correspond to the value in the correct group, but for index i, i+1, ... until the period.
This look ahead in the index seems to contrast with the rolling_mean function which (by default) the values of lower indices, not higher, to perform the rolling mean.

Is it intentionally designed this way, and if so, how can one perform a groupby_dynamic using lower indices? (i am not sure what the offset parameter does, but not what i want here)

Here is an example, using polars 0.16.16 from pypi, that i expected not to raise

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "index": [0, 0, 1, 1],
        "group": ["banana", "pear", "banana", "pear"],
        "weight": [2, 3, 5, 7],
    }
)


agg = df.groupby_dynamic("index", by="group", every="1i", period="2i").agg(pl.col("weight"))

assert((
    agg
    .filter((pl.col("index") == 0) & (pl.col("group") == "banana"))
    .select("weight")
    .to_series()
    .to_list()
) == [[2]])
```

Thank you

Comment: For `banana`, the first window is `[2, 5]` and the second window is `[5]`, If you want `[2], [2, 5]` it would be `.groupby_rolliing` but it's not clear why `index 1` would end up being `[2]`?

Comment: Sorry, meant index == 0 in the select context, i corrected it.

I thought the groupby_rolling had no every argument, and that when rolling windows overlapped one should use groupby_dynamic and not groupby_rolling.

Comment: @jqurious  why would one want to have the first window to be [2, 5] when a simple rolling_mean here would not take the mean of 2 and 5?

Comment: You're right, `_rolling` has no `every=`, the every is kind of implied. As for why you would want `[2, 5]`, it depends on your use-case. @Luca has shown a nice example of both, in which you can see the rolling approach is sort of like the "opposite/inverse" of the dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @jqurious mentioned, a solution can be `groupby_rolling`.

With your example:

```
df.groupby_dynamic("index", by="group", every="1i", period="2i").agg(pl.col("weight"))

# result
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ group  ┆ index ┆ weight    │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ banana ┆ 0     ┆ [2, 5]    │
│ banana ┆ 1     ┆ [5]       │
│ pear   ┆ 0     ┆ [3, 7]    │
│ pear   ┆ 1     ┆ [7]       │
└────────┴───────┴───────────┘

df.groupby_rolling(index_column="index", period="2i", by="group").agg(pl.col("weight"))

# result
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬───────┬───────────┐
│ group  ┆ index ┆ weight    │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════╪═══════════╡
│ banana ┆ 0     ┆ [2]       │
│ banana ┆ 1     ┆ [2, 5]    │
│ pear   ┆ 0     ┆ [3]       │
│ pear   ┆ 1     ┆ [3, 7]    │
└────────┴───────┴───────────┘
```